# Java JDBC SQLite database locked by a select with where clause

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc, locked

I'm calling this method:

```
ArrayList<String> selectFilteredJump(String owner, String fromDate, String toDate, String env) {
    ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<>();
    Connection c;
    Statement stmt;

    StringBuilder whereClause = new StringBuilder("WHERE a.Date BETWEEN '"+fromDate+ "' and '" + toDate+"'");
    if (!env.equals(constants.EMPTY) ) {
        whereClause.append(" and a.Environment = '").append(env).append("'");
    }

    if (!owner.equals(constants.EMPTY) ) {
        whereClause.append(" and a.UserId = '").append(owner).append("'");
    }

    String sql = "SELECT a.TicketID, a.Subject, a.UserID, a.Date, a.Solution, a.Comments," +
                 "a.Environment, (SELECT UserName FROM Users WHERE UserID = a.UserID) AS UserName FROM Tickets a " +
                 whereClause + " order by 4 asc;";
    System.out.println(sql);
    try {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + this.dbPath + this.dbName) ;
        c.setAutoCommit(false);
        stmt = c.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        while (rs.next()) {
            a.add(rs.getString("TicketID"));
            a.add(rs.getString("Subject"));
            a.add(rs.getString("UserID"));
            a.add(rs.getString("Date"));
            a.add(rs.getString("Solution"));
            a.add(rs.getString("Comments"));
            a.add(rs.getString("Environment"));
            a.add(rs.getString("UserName"));
        }
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        c.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return a;
}
```

Everything executes correctly but it seems that my database remains locked with no visible reason.

On the other side if I'm replacing with this method the database is ok after executing it:

```
    ArrayList<String> selectAllJump() {
    if (constants.DEBUG_MODE) System.out.println("selectAllJump");
    ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<>();
    Connection c;
    Statement stmt;
    try {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + this.dbPath + this.dbName);
        c.setAutoCommit(false);
        stmt = c.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT a.TicketID, a.Subject, a.UserID, a.Date, a.Solution, a.Comments," +
                "a.Environment, (SELECT UserName FROM Users WHERE UserID = a.UserID) AS UserName FROM Tickets a " +
                "order by 4 asc;");
        while (rs.next()) {
            a.add(rs.getString("TicketID"));
            a.add(rs.getString("Subject"));
            a.add(rs.getString("UserID"));
            a.add(rs.getString("Date"));
            a.add(rs.getString("Solution"));
            a.add(rs.getString("Comments"));
            a.add(rs.getString("Environment"));
            a.add(rs.getString("UserName"));
        }
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        c.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return a;
}
```

I've also tried to open the connection using specific configuration (like this):

```
c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + this.dbPath + this.dbName,setConfig().toProperties()) ;

private SQLiteConfig setConfig() {
    SQLiteConfig config = new SQLiteConfig();
    config.enforceForeignKeys(true);
    config.setTempStore(SQLiteConfig.TempStore.MEMORY);
    config.setCacheSize(1000);
    config.setReadOnly(true);
    return config;
}
```

and still the same error:

**org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_BUSY]  The database file is locked (database is locked)**

Any idea is welcomed.

Thank you.

Comment: you should learn how to write a proper join instead of doing a sub-query inside the main query (`(SELECT UserName FROM Users WHERE UserID = a.UserID)`). Maybe this is also the issue with the first example since you have a WHERE clause that uses UserID. Did you try the first code with owner = "" to exclude the last part of the WHERE?

Comment: Irrelevant. Even like this I'm having the same result    String sql = "SELECT a.TicketID, a.Subject, a.UserID, a.Date, a.Solution, a.Comments," +
                     "a.Environment, b.UserName FROM Tickets a " +
                     " join Users b on a.UserID = b.UserID "+
                     whereClause + " order by 4 asc;";